# How to relate the definition of mapping cylinder from homological algebra to topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I'm now learning triangulated categories and I have to work with the Homotopy category. There are distinguished triangles presented by cones and cylinders. However, I cannot understand the definition of them in an algebraic setting. I cannot take it as granted either, because they seem messy compared to the definition of homotopy. The questions are

1. Are there references on algebraic topology showing the naturality of definition by computation?
2. Is it easy to view the lengthy proofs that Homotopy category forms a triangulated category from topological insights?

Comment: What you probably want is to read a book on model categories. Or did you already do this?

Comment: I have no knowledge about that. Do you mean Gelfand-Manin? @Pedro

Comment: For your first question, I'm not sure what you mean by "the naturality of definition by computation". Would you mind clarifying? For your second question, yes. Many proofs about derived categories filter through topological intuition. At the level of triangulated categories we can already see this basically by replacing all your spaces by cell complexes. Then you can see what the topological operations on your spaces induce on their chain complexes, and ask "what if we did this to _general_ complexes?". See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001045.pdf), for instance.

Comment: I mean how the scary definition of mapping cylinder in homological algebra comes from a topology setting. Your link has some illustration of ideas. It seems that detailed calculation is left for me, but at least I know where to start.